# Folder being mistaken for module Error: no module named "GAN"

Tags: python, github, bioinformatics, generative-adversarial-network

I'm running this github project: https://github.com/Biomatter-Designs/ProteinGAN
the second step says **2. Run the training script with python train_gan.** but when I run the file I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/user/Desktop/ProteinGAN-master/src/gan/train_gan.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/ProteinGAN-master/src/gan/train_gan.py", line 8, in <module>
    from gan.models import get_model, get_specific_hooks
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gan'
```

I don't understand why it thinks the GAN folder is a module.

Comment: Because that's how Python works.  `gan` is a module that either contains a file called `models.py` or another module called `models`.  Make sure you `cd` to the `.../src` folder before starting Python.  Then it should be able to find `gan`.

Comment: I typed cd src and my terminal says (base) Mac:src nickrizzolo$  but it still does not work.

Comment: Do `cp gan/train_gan.py .` and then run `python train_gan.py`.

Comment: That has worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Had the issue error trying to import gan files on google colab.

I corrected my /content/gdrive folder to the exact path and it worked.
I hope this helps out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).